# How do I compile a greek letter in PyLaTeX into a table?

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I am trying to do a code to create a LaTex table from Python implementing PyLaTeX. Two cells of the table I want them to be greek letters, like [what is shown in the image][1]. Look at my block of code and see that I am typing `'\gamma'` and `'\gamma_{sat}'` but it does not work, just print it textually, does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

I have tried typing `'\\gamma'` , `r'\gamma'`, `'$\gamma'`.... but I just don't know how to do it.

```
# Creo una subsección para las tablas. 
    with doc.create(Subsection('Tablas de interés', numbering = False)):
        # Creo el entorno Table.
        with doc.create(Table(position='h!')) as entorno_table:
            # Creo el entorno Center.
            with entorno_table.create(Center()) as centered:
                # Creo el entorno Tabular.
                with centered.create(Tabular('|c|c|c|c|c|')) as entorno_tabular:
                    # Construyo la tabla.
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('Estrato', 'Profundidad Inicial', 'Profundidad final', '\gamma', '\gamma_{sat}'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('1', '0', '1', '14.6', '18.38'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('2', '1', '2.5', '14.9', '18.48'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('3', '2.5', '5', '15.2', '18.58'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('4', '5', '6.7', '15.5', '18.68'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    entorno_tabular.add_row(('5', '6.7', '10', '15.8', '18.78'))
                    entorno_tabular.add_hline()
                    #table.add_empty_row()
            # Añado el caption al entorno Table.
            entorno_table.add_caption('Propiedades del suelo para pregunta ##.')


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPC6d.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NoEscape` to get the Latex commands out into the document. You also need to put the gammas in math mode `$.. $`.

```
from pylatex import Document, Subsection, Table, Tabular, Center, NoEscape # ...

# ...
    entorno_tabular.add_row(('Estrato', 'Profundidad Inicial', 'Profundidad final', NoEscape('$\gamma$'), NoEscape('$\gamma_{sat}$')))
# ...
```

Comment: It does not work, I get this error: ```subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['latexmk', '--pdf', '--interaction=nonstopmode ... returned non-zero exit status 12.```. Do you know what is happening ?

Comment: Is there any other error message before that?

Comment: Oh I see. I just answered the part with the gamma command. It also needs to be put in math mode. I updated the answer.